# Graph implementation C++ with unsized vectors

Tags: c++, list, graph, vector

So, I'm trying to make a graph of vectors. 
The thing is, I don't know the size of the vectors, it is given to my as an input.
I was thinking about making a node as such:

```
typedef struct node{
   my_vector v[];
   node * next;
}
```

can I create a node with a vector as in line `my_vector v[];`? I'm really new to c++

Also, I don't really know how to implement a graph, but is it different from implementing a list?

Comment: If you want to store vectors, you can use `std::vector`.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "graph of vectors" by giving a small example?

Comment: @molbdnilo thank you
@uba what I meant was a graph where each node is 
   `typedef struct node{
      std::vector <my_type> my_vector;
      node * next;
   }`

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
template<typename T>
struct node{
   std::vector<T> v;
   node * next;
}
```

Now you can create `node`s which contain any type of data, like so:

```
node<int> myintnode;
node<double> mydoublenode;
```

Answer (score 0):

> can I create a node with a vector as in line my_vector v[];

If you need to decide the vector size during the run time, you cannot use this kind of declaration. You will have to allocate the memory yourself, or even better, use `std::vector`.

> Also, I don't really know how to implement a graph, but is it different from implementing a list?

A list is a very simple graph, so there are some *theoretical* similarities. In practice implementations differ and depend on what you will do with the graph. There are many ways to implement graphs and there are many books and libraries that deal with the subject. I would propose to look into any introduction into data structures for simple graph implementations. For example, [Adjacency Lists](http://opendatastructures.org/versions/edition-0.1e/ods-java/12_2_AdjacencyLists_Graph_a.html) and [Adjacency Matrix](http://opendatastructures.org/versions/edition-0.1e/ods-java/12_1_AdjacencyMatrix_Repres.html) are some of the most common graph representations. There is also [graph library in Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html), but it will probably be an overkill.